# Custom 'Devise' user field that has been generated from a third party api?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, devise, httparty

I was wondering if anyone would be able to help me out. I am currently building an application that is using Rails 4.2 and I am also using these two gems for this current problem.

The two gems are: 'HTTParty' as well as 'Devise'

The use case is that I want a user to be able to sign up for my application through Devise but there will be a custom field that the user will provide their zip code and with the help of this API: *http://www.ed.gov/developer* be able to select from a list of schools that are close to the provided zip.

I am mainly looking for some example rails apps that did something similar and then I can reverse engineer from that.

Thank you so much in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the ZipCode to the User Model and add that in that field to the view

```
rails g migration AddZipcodeToUsers zip_code:string
```

#### app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb

```
...
f.text_field :zip_code
```

Comment: Am I just overthinking how the API would interact with the devise sign_up? Also I am looking for best practices when placing an API with Rails app.